# SSIS Map a variable or an SQL command to a column

Tags: dictionary, ssis

I'm facing an issue, I don't know how to map the result of an `SQL command` or even a `variable` to a `column`.

Here's what I'm trying to do :
I have an `ADO source` (DB1) which I want to map to different tables (`DB2.table1, ..., DB2.table_5`), so I'm using a `broadcast tool`, with a flow per table, but one of my destination table requires that one field be mapped to the result of a select query. So I thought of variables which can be assigned the result of a command, but an `ADO destination` appears not to map a `column` with neither a `query` nor a `variable`.

SQL Server 2008 + Visual 2008.

Has anyone a solution ?
Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: broadcast tool ?? U meant multicast component right ?

Comment: Hi, yeah that's what I meant but had no idea of its English name

Answer (score 1):

The [Derived Column transformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141069(v=sql.105).aspx) supports using variables, as well as existing column values, to determine new column values. This screenshot shows how to use the `System::StartTime` variable to replace the value of `ColumnA`:

[image]